# Guardar el id de un modelo como llave foranea de otro

Tags: django

Tengo estos 2 modelos:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    opciones = [('masculino', 'Masculino'), ('femenino', 'Femenino')]

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    curp = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    rfc = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=70, choices=opciones)

class Vacaciones(models.Model):
    dias_tomados = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField()
    razon = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    observaciones = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    personas = models.ForeignKey(Persona, null=True, blank=True)
```

Este es el `form`:

```
class VacacionesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vacaciones

        fields = [
            'dias_tomados',
            'fecha_inicio',
            'razon',
            'observaciones',
        ]

        labels = {
            'dias_tomados': 'Días tomados',
            'fecha_inicio': 'Fecha de inicio',
            'razon': 'Razón',
            'observaciones': 'Observaciones',
        }

        widgets = {
            'dias_tomados': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'fecha_inicio': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'razon': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'observaciones': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Y este es la `view`:

```
def AsignaVacaciones(request, prs_id):
    persona = Persona.objects.get(id=prs_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VacacionesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('personas:listado_persona')
    else:
        form = VacacionesForm()
    return render(request, 'vacaciones/vacaciones_form.html', {'vacaciones':form})
```

Estoy tratando de colocar el `id` de las personas que solicitan sus vacaciones en el campo `personas` (`FK`) del modelo `Vacaciones` pero hasta ahora no lo he conseguido. he estado buscando como llevar acabo esta relación pero nada me ha funcionado.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Es posible realizar esta relación desde las `views`?.

En el `template` se ve de de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta este punto ya se ha recuperado el `id` de la persona que desea solicitar sus vacaciones, pero no consigo que el id de la persona se guarde como valor del campo `personas_id` del modelo `Vacaciones`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes de mostrar como lo estas guardando, te sugiero que añadas la vista, y el formulario en caso de usar uno.

Comment: Gracias por respoder German, ya estan anexos tanto la el formulario como la vista.

Comment: ¿Graba el objeto persona? Django trabaja con ORM y no directamente en la capa SQL por lo que lo que habitualmente guarda es el **objeto** persona (no el id, aunque esto sea lo que puede mostrar en la interfaz de administración si no has definido un __str__ distinto para el modelo). Normalmente no requiere siquiera intervención para hacer la transacción. Con este paradigma de funcionamiento, lo que tienes que solicitar en la vista (si quieres el id y no otro campo) es `persona.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando comenté que añadieras la vista y el formulario, lo hice con el fin de que fueras más especifico, es decir, no sé si tienes el control de que estas enviando al servidor, en tu formulario HTML, y qué esperas recibir en el servidor. Sin embargo el problema que veo, y puede dar solución a lo que necesitas es lo siguiente:

En tu vista:

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = VacacionesForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.persona = persona
        instance.save()
...
```

Al no ser tan especifico y debo guiarme por las imágenes, supongo que eso servirá. En todo caso, te recomiendo que leas bien que trae `request.POST` para que sepas que estas enviando desde el formulario en HTML y ayudarte a aclarar tu problema

Comment: Buen día German, estuve probando tu método pero de igual modo no me da resultado, en cuanto a lo que estoy recibiendo en el servidor efectivamente es el valor que requiero (**id** del solicitante), por el momento la unica solución que encontré, fue anexar otro campo en el modelo **vacaciones** en donde guardo el **id** del solicitante, ya que no encontre alguna forma de guardar este dato en campo **personas_id**, te agardezco tu tiempo y tu apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

En tu vista:

```
...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VacacionesForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.personas = persona
            instance.save()
...
```

pasando la instancia a la clave funciona